# How to ask if things are related

Tags: phrase-choice

1. Has it **got anything** to do with this?
2. Has it **got something** to do with this?
3. Has it **something** to do with this?
4. Has it **anything** to do with this?

I am not sure which is correct and natural in English. The immediate context is:

> You look tired, **has it got anything to do with** air pollution?

Answer (score 2):

As a native AE speaker, I would probably say "Does it have anything to do with air pollution?"

Comment: Or "Does it have something to do with ...". I think both versions, anything or something, or common and valid. "Has it anything to do with ..." is valid but sounds archaic.

Answer (score 0):

As a native BrE speaker, I would probably say *Is it anything to do with this?* (or *"something"* - they're normally about equal and interchangeable). But AmE does seem to favour ***get*** in such constructions.

Per @Jay's comment, OP's versions #3 and #4 are dated/formal (*archaic* is putting it a bit strong).

---

In some related contexts, there *are* different implications regarding *anything/something*. For example,...

> *"I hear you found a dead body near my house, officer..."*
>    *"...is that anything to do with me?"*  (implies denial of involvement - *"It's **nothing** to do with me"*)
>    *"...is that something to do with me?"*  (implies a genuine enquiry - *"Is it someone I know, perhaps?"*)